# PHP/MySQL - Passar do localhost para um alojamento online

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Eu criei um site com PHP e com uma base de dados em MySQL utilizando o XAMPP. Agora gostava de por o site online num host, tenho que mudar a conexão à base de dados onde diz localhost?

Quais os procedimentos tenho que fazer?

Answer (score 1):

São muitos procedimentos a serem seguidos que irei listar de uma forma geral, podendo variar de caso a caso. Se não se sentir seguro, é recomendável solicitar um técnico ou alguém experiente.

**1. Nome de domínio**

Escolha um nome de domínio para o seu site (ex.: meusite.com.br). Escolha um nome mais curto possível e que tenha a ver com o propósito do site, pois ele será como uma "identidade" do site.

Caso você queira um domínio brasileiro (ex., com.br), entre no [registro.br](https://registro.br/) e registre o seu domínio, pois lá costuma ser mais barato do que em sites de hospedagem, exceto quando os mesmos dão registro de domínio grátis quando você contrata uma hospedagem. Isso pode variar muito de empresa pra empresa.

Caso queira registrar um domínio estrangeiro (ex., .com), você pode fazer isso diretamente na própria empresa de hospedagem caso ela disponha desse serviço.

> O domínio pode demorar algumas horas para entrar em vigor após o
>   registro.

**2. Hospedagem**

Contrate uma hospedagem que irá suprir sua demanda (se há suporte para a versão do PHP que você usa, o banco de dados que você usa, limite de tráfego confortável, espaço de armazenamento suficiente etc.). Eles irão te informar os dados de acesso do FTP (servidor, usuário e senha) que será o meio de você enviar os arquivos para o servidor.

Caso tenha feito o registro do domínio no registro.br, será necessário informar no painel do registro.br os servidores DNS da sua hospedagem, para que o domínio aponte para lá (os servidores DNS você pode encontrar no suporte da hospedagem).

**3. Criação do banco de dados e envio dos arquivos**

Crie o banco de dados no servidor da hospedagem e migre as tabelas para lá. Geralmente as hospedagens dispõem de um painel administrativo (ex.: phpMyAdmin, Painel de Controle etc.) onde você pode administrar o banco de dados. Altere no seu arquivo PHP de conexão com o banco o host, usuário e senha de acordo com o banco de dados remoto.

Use um programa cliente de FTP para fazer o envio dos arquivos para o servidor. Recomendo usar o [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client), que tem uma interface parecida com o gerenciador de arquivos do Windows, basta arrastar os arquivos para a pasta remota, que geralmente se chama "public_html/" no servidor.

**4. Finalizando**

Após todas estas etapas: domínio registrado, banco criado e arquivos enviados, faça um teste abrindo o site no navegador para ver se está tudo funcionando.

Estes são os procedimentos básicos. Como dito no início, pode variar de caso a caso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. A minha dúvida principal é mesmo em relação à base de dados, porque na base de dados que criei no php admin na conexão tem lá localhost, o user e a pass. Se eu criar a base de dados novamente ja com o site no host as configurações vão ser na mesma localhost ou tenho que dar o ip?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você precisa contratar uma hospedagem. Uma vez que ela tenha sido contratada então você precisará pegar os seus arquivos do site e subir no armazenamento da hospedagem (isso é geralmente feito via FTP se você não usa Git).

Lembre-se de **nunca** colocar senhas e usuários dentro do seu código. Eles são relativos a ambiente, a maioria das hospedagens suportam a passagem de variáveis de ambiente, se não, você pode criar um arquivo com a extensão `.ini` e utilizar a função `parse_ini_file` do PHP para trazer seus dados de banco.

A partir daí é criar uma base na hospedagem e apontar pra lá.